# Calendar with time slot reservation

Tags: php, mysql, calendar

I'm very new in this site. Spend a lot of time for searching an answer for my target, but unsuccessfully. So, there it is (sorry for my english):

I'm quite new in php, but already created nice stuff. But now I'm interested in calendar with time slot reservation. I saw good exemple then I registered for my doctor. There i was able to choose a day from calendar and then select a free time range (e.g. from 12:00 to 12:30).

First idea for this is some calendar in PHP and table in MySQL. In MySQL table few rows with id, name and quantity. id - unique number of row, name - date and time slot, and quantity - (1 = free cell, 0 = unable). In PHP calendar after selecting a free time slot, in DB quantity goes from 1 to 0 and apear unavailable for other users.

But if where are a lots of "doctors"? How to make calendar, DB for thousands of them?

For the beggining maybie someone have some example how to make calendar with time reservation (e.g. 1 hour) in the easiest way? Or suggest something?

Comment: I've successfully built a similar system for booking of a shared meeting room, for the frontend I used https://github.com/themouette/jquery-week-calendar , which has ajax hooks where you call your php scripts to save/load calendar events from mysql. Good luck with your project!.

Comment: Hey, have you look at OpenEMR(http://www.oemr.org/) ? it has everything between doctor and patient with appointment scheduling, etc.... You can customise it as per your needs, why reinventing the wheel.